# Redirect in htaccess to folder and https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

Using htaccess I want to force http to https and at the same time redirect to www. and to the 'public' folder where my application files are. 
The result should be that `http://example.com` should redirect to `https://www.example.com/public/`

To redirect to https and www I manage by using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

To redirect to the 'public' folder I manage by using:

```
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Now I need to combine these but my many attempts did not result in a working redirect and I would need some advise on this.

EDIT:
In the folder public is another htaccess file:

```
 SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "production"
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

<<

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess

Comment: `ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]` - note that this is an _internal rewrite_, not a "redirect" (which implies an _external redirect_) as you've stated in the question. Presumably your URLs don't actually contain the `/public` subdirectory and this is not exposed to your users?

Comment: @MrWhite that is correct. It is an internal rewrite.

Comment: @anubhava at this point this is my htaccess, with `RewriteEngine On` on top.

Comment: These rules are correct and order as shown in question is also right.

Comment: @anubhava okay but it does not redirect to https. I think I should incorporate the rewrite to public in the redirect to https?

Comment: @zef Don't "incorporate the rewrite to public in the redirect to https" - that would expose the `/public` subdirectory to your users. The canonical redirect and rewrite to `/public` need to be kept separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public/
> ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
> ```

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable starts with a slash, so the condition above will never match. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

However, assuming you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/public` subdirectory I would write this block like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

This has the added benefit of allowing a `public` path segment at the start of your URLs (if you wish). eg. The URL `/public/foo` would internally rewrite to `/public/public/foo` without creating a rewrite loop.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC] 
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC] 
> RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
> ```

You are missing an `OR` flag on the first condition. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
:
```

Without that, it will fail to redirect `http://www.example.com/` to HTTPS.

Just to clarify, the canonical redirect should go before the internal rewrite to the `public` directory.

---

**UPDATE:**

> EDIT: In the folder public is another htaccess file:
>
> ```
> SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "production"
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
> RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
> RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
> ```

The *substitution* string on the last `RewriteRule` directive is incorrect. You need to remove the slash prefix from `/index.php`. It should just read `index.php`. Otherwise it is going to rewrite the request back to the document root (filesystem path) and result in either an endless loop or a 404 (depending on the parent directives). By changing it to `index.php` (no slash) it is now relative to the `/public` directory (the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file), instead of the document root.

You can also simplify the `RewriteRule` *pattern* and the `NC` flag is not required here. So, in summary, the `/public/.htaccess` file should read:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "production"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I have been testing but with no success. The redirect to https is now okay but then it stops. Using a htaccess tester it says the condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/` or `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` is not met.

Comment: What URL are you requesting? And these are the only directives you have in your root `.htaccess` file? (HTTPS redirect before the rewrite) Do you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/public` subdirectory? (If so, what is in this `.htaccess` file?)

Comment: I have added the other `.htaccess` file from the `/public` subdirectory. The url request I am testing is `http://example.com`. With your suggested options I either get: `The requested URL was not found` or `too many redirects`.

Comment: Ah, the `/public/.htaccess` is not correct. You need to remove the slash prefix from `/index.php`, to become `index.php`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Updating the `/public/.htaccess` accordingly results in too many redirects.

Comment: Make sure you've cleared your browser cache. And you are using the `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` version in the root `.htaccess` file? If you remove the `/public/.htaccess` file do you still get a redirect loop? Does the HTTP to HTTPS redirect work correctly? What exactly is the nature of the redirect loop? (Check the network traffic in the browser... Requested URL and `Location:` response header.)

Comment: Cache is cleared. I use a new incognito window everytime I check. I am using the `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` version in the root `.htaccess` file. If I remove the `/public/.htaccess` file I get `The requested URL /nl/home was not found on this server.`. HTTP is not redirected to HTTPS. If I check the developertools I see a loop from https to http back and forth.

Comment: Hhhmmm, there seems to be multiple issues going on here. Where is `/nl/home` coming from? How does this relate to your system? You need to focus on one thing at once... have you ever had a HTTP to HTTPS redirect working? There is no code here that would redirect back to HTTP - have you any idea where that might be coming from? Are you using a front-end proxy? eg. Cloudflare, etc.? Do you have anything in the document root? Remove all `.htaccess` and examine the value of the `HTTPS` server variable (or `HTTPS` env var) when accessing `https://...`.

Comment: Yes it seems the problem might be located elsewhere. I will need to look into it. Thanks a lot for your help! I will get back.

Comment: Turns out there was a Https request handler plugin active that for some reason redirected back to http causing all the trouble. With your help and above changes it is now working. Thanks again!