# Laravel : How to redirect my main domain to a subfolder in public?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect

I have a Laravel project and I want my main domain to be redirected to a subfolder IN the public folder, but I don't want the `public` in the URL.

For example, when I type `example.com`, I want to be automaticaly redirected to `example.com/english`.

I know that I can redirect `example.com` to `example.com/public/english` like so :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/english/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/english/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/english/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

and I can remove the `public` like so :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] #relative substitution
</IfModule>
```

But how do I combine both ?

Comment: Looks very similar to this recent question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937631/redirect-in-htaccess-to-folder-and-https

Comment: Your server should be configured to have the document root be the public folder, not the application root. This is done for security reasons. Once you have the server configured to serve the application out of the `public` directory adding the redirect to a subdirectory should be trivial.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you need. VS. Where is the content actually located? What address for that content to you want to be in the address bar? Is the content in the folder `/public/english`, but you want the address bar to display `/english `? (where I've left of the `https://example.com` prom, showing the relative address only?)

Answer (score 0):

First, the difference between redirect and rewrite:

**Redirect**:  Changes URL in browser address bar

**Rewrite**:  URL in browser address bar does NOT change

The `[R]` flag on a `RewriteRule` makes it a **redirect**.  Also, if the host changes, it will be a redirect.  Otherwise, it is a **rewrite**.

So perhaps step 1 could be to set what's in the address bar, client-side:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/english/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /english/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /english/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

But the content does not actually exist there, so now, once the new request comes through, we rewrite that one internally, server-side, to direct the request to the actual location of the content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] #relative substitution
</IfModule>
```

You should be able to combine that into a single `<IfModule> .. </IfModule>` code block.

Alongside the `R` flag, you can indicate if its a permanent or a temporary redirect.  By default it will be a permanent redirect (301 status code). I generally test it out using as temporary redirect `[R=302]`, in case of mistake, until I'm confident everything works as expected.

---

The page flow for the two types differ:
**redirect**: Client side - (hence the browser's address bar changes)

1. Browser requests a page
2. Server responds with a redirect status code
   (301: Permanent, 302: Found, 303: See Other, 307: Temporary)
3. Browser makes 2nd request to the new URL
4. Server responds to the new URL

**rewrite**:  Server side (hence the browser bar does NOT change)

1. Browser requests a page
2. URL Rewrite rewrites the URL and makes request for the updated page